# Getting error not recognized by any processor while using Jetpack compose with Hilt

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to create a project with Jetpack Compose and I try to use Hilt. These are the dependencies I'm using:

**build.gradle**:

```
`plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android'

//    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
}
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    namespace 'com.mawgif.composeapp3'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mawgif.composeapp3"
        minSdk 26
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.4.2'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.6.1'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_ui_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_ui_version"
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material:1.3.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_ui_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_ui_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:$compose_ui_version"

    // Kotlin components
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlinVersion"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$coroutines"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.4"

    // Lifecycle components
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycleVersion"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.5.1"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycleVersion"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:$lifecycleVersion"

    // networking
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:2.9.0'
    implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:5.0.0-alpha.1")
    implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:5.0.0-alpha.1")
    implementation "com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:$moshi_version"
    kapt "com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin-codegen:$moshi_version"

    // coil
    implementation("io.coil-kt:coil-compose:1.4.0")

    // dagger -hilt
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.45'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.45'
    kapt "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0"
}

project level **build.gradle**:
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_ui_version = '1.3.3'
        kotlinVersion = '1.8.10'
        coroutines = '1.5.0'
        lifecycleVersion = '2.5.1'
        moshi_version = '1.12.0'
    }
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.10' apply false
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' version '2.45' apply false
}`
```

Error at Rebuild:
The following options were not recognized by any processor: '[dagger.fastInit, dagger.hilt.android.internal.disableAndroidSuperclassValidation, dagger.hilt.android.internal.projectType, dagger.hilt.internal.useAggregatingRootProcessor, kapt.kotlin.generated]'

Comment: remove this dependency `kapt "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0"` from build.gradle file (module)

Comment: tried, removed kapt "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0", still having same error, not fixed

Comment: Issue resolved after moshi_version change: 
from moshi_version = '1.12.0' to moshi_version = '1.14.0'